# Setting up Yeoman with Django

Tags: django, gruntjs, yeoman

Has anyone being able to get [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) to work with Django??
I've tried to set it up and even if i change my grunt file to the correct paths its still uses the default.

I've searched only but it doesnt that anyone is using such file structure.

Comment: I would personally recommend that you use brunch with django instead - https://github.com/sebastibe/brunch-django-examples   Brunch is also a more matured library compared to yeoman. But this does not answer your original question. Hence, only a comment here. :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So that was a really stupid comment I made above. :-)

Here's a proper response!  Yeoman is simply a scaffolding tool for us to quickly generate css, js and html files. I am using it in a completely decoupled way, cleanly separated from django.

Here's the tree structure of the frontend site.

```
/Users/calvin/work/yeoman-test/
|~app/
| |~scripts/
| | |~controllers/
| | | `-main.js
| | |~vendor/
| | | |-angular.js
| | | |-angular.min.js
| | | |-es5-shim.min.js
| | | `-json3.min.js
| | `-app.js
| |~styles/
| | |-bootstrap.css
| | `-main.css
| |+views/
| |-.buildignore
| |-.htaccess
| |-404.html
| |-favicon.ico
| |-index.html
| `-robots.txt
|~test/
| |+spec/
| `+vendor/
|-.gitattributes
|-.npmignore
|-Gruntfile.js
|-package.json
`-testacular.conf.js
```

And here's the tree structure for the django application acting as a pure json web-service. Using django-tastypie.

```
/Users/calvin/work/yeomandjango/
|~deploy/
| |-crontab
| |-gunicorn.conf.py
| |-live_settings.py*
| |-nginx.conf
| `-supervisor.conf
|~requirements/
| `-project.txt
|+static/
|-.gitignore
|-.hgignore
|-__init__.py
|-__init__.pyc
|-dev.db
|-fabfile.py
|-local_settings.py
|-local_settings.pyc
|-manage.py*
|-settings.py
|-settings.pyc
|-urls.py
`-urls.pyc
```

By running the django web service from domain and urls such as http://service.mysite.com/api/v1/ and having our frontend yeoman generated "static" site http://mysite.com calling these API urls as needed.

The yeoman generated AngularJS app simply POSTS/GETS/PUTS/DELETES the api resources/urls given by our django-tastypie APIs.

This is a loosely coupled configuration you can consider.

However, do note that this set-up is performing "cross-domain API requests".  This means that on our "server-side" django application, we will need to handle CORS.

Here's an example middleware snippet that needs to be implemented at django server side for this to work.

```
import re

from django.utils.text import compress_string
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

from django import http

try:
    import settings 
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS
except:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = '*'
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST','GET','OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']


class XsSharing(object):
    """
        This middleware allows cross-domain XHR using the html5 postMessage API.


        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
    """
    def process_request(self, request):

        if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS 
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS ) 

            return response

        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # Avoid unnecessary work
        if response.has_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'):
            return response

        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS 
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS )

        return response
```

Comment: How do you get to locally call the django api from your frontend for dev porpuses?

Comment: Very simple...run Django local server and frontend dev server on different ports. Then you can configure your angular or any frontend frameworks to call localhost:django-server-port for data accordingly.

Comment: Hey Calvin, how do you deploy your yeoman project? You use fabfile for Django I think but wonder how it works for yeoman project especially if there are some grunt tasks etc.

Comment: The Django Rest Framework documentation suggests a related approach for inserting the server headers with CORS: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

Comment: @brsbilgic A frontend site is essentially a collection of html/js/css - completely static and loaded into the user's browser the first time he/she loads up your site.  So any script that sends your static files (even a simple rsync) into your server will do just fine.  The only thing you need to do is to make sure that your nginx config (or whatever webserver you use on your server) is set up to serve these static files.

So you don't need fabfiles.  In any case, I have stopped using fabric and moved on to ansible to automate all my deployment needs.